# How to check if parameters from non-linear curve fits on two datasets are statistically significant?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing

I have two datasets. They measure a physical response Y (in a certain sample) with increasing concentrations (X) of a certain molecule (dose response). I fit my datasets to a model known as one site specific binding model, that takes the form:

Y = Bmax*X/(Kd + X).

The parameters that are computed from the curve fitting are Bmax and Kd. For each data-set, for each value of X, I do three independent replicates and I normally use the software called Prism to simply paste the triplicate values, and it computes Kd values for me using the one-site specific model.

For each dataset, the program gives me the value of the parameter Kd, along with Standard Error and 95% Confidence Intervals.

How can I do a t-test on these computed Kd values, to check if the calculated Kd values are statistically different across the two datasets (representing responses from two different molecules on the same system)? Is it at all appropriate to do a t-test in this case, and if not, why?

I would greatly appreciate any help or insights about this.

Comment: In particular, I want to ask if I can just take the two best-fit Kd values and their associated standard errors, assuming degrees of freedom, N=(Number of data points - number of parameters fit), and check for statistical significance of the difference in (means) of the best-fit Kds?

Comment: "Statistically significant" doesn't mean anything any more.  State your real goal.  Usually it's estimation, for which compatibility intervals (aka confidence intervals) are a good idea.

Comment: I want to do a t-test on the best fit Kd values. In principle, I know the following from the best-fit Kd parameter values, for each data-set: 

Kd (estimate), Standard Error, Degrees of freedom 

How can I use this information to do a t test?

Comment: Although you can do a t-test, and it can be meaningful, the nature of the model suggests first establishing that the sampling variance of the $K_d$ estimate is approximately Normal.  Have you done that, or is there literature studying this question?

Comment: This is a good point and I will look into it. However, if I assume for now that the sampling variance of the Kd estimate is approximately normal, how can I do a t-test to compare two Kd estimates (assuming I know their associated SEMs)? On Prism, there is an option that allows me to enter Mean, Standard Error and N, and this can be done for two (or as many) data-sets and from this one do a t-test (assuming normal distribution). However, I am not sure what I should choose as N? Is N the total number of data points that I fit for each curve? Or is it the number of replicates (N=3 in that case)?

Comment: If you can enter a standard error, then $N$ is irrelevant.  If an application requires you to enter both, then (at best) it is misusing standard statistical terminology and (at worst) it will be doing erroneous calculations.

Comment: https://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ttest1/?format=SEM

Why does it ask for N then?

Comment: Any helpful comments would be very much appreciated.